# Selecting next element in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( ".clicker" ).click(function() {
    //var fid = $( this ).parent().next().find('.plus-minus').attr('id');
    var fid = $( this ).next().attr('id');
    console.log(fid);
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<h5><?=$awardyear?> <span id="here" class="clicker hover"><img src="/_images/<?=($i==1?'minus':'plus');?>.gif" class="plus-minus" id="iconwinners<?=$awardyear?>" /></span></h5>
```

I'm trying to get the id of the img tag...can't figure out for the life of me why it's returning undefined.  Thanks!

Comment: the img isn't next - it's a child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  var fid = $( this ).find('img').attr('id');

Answer (score 0):

The image is inside the span, so you can't use the next() method for that. You should use children() instead.

Answer (score 0):

You currently have:

```
<h5>
    <span>
    </span>
</h5>
```

Your jquery is on `<span>` and you're telling it to goto the next element (on the same tree level), but there is no element. However this would work:

```
<h5>
    <span>
    </span>
    <img/>
</h5>
```

I think what you meant to do was

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( ".clicker" ).click(function() {
    var fid = $( "img", this ).attr('id');
    console.log(fid);
  });
});
```

This says that on `this` ( the current element `.clicker` ), find inside it an `img`